# Laravel 3 way pivot when two column come from same id

Tags: laravel-5

How can i set up this, i'm trying to build a student and teacher lesson schedule, here is my code.

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('photo_url')->nullable();
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->string('username')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->date('date_of_birth');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timeTz('timezone');
        $table->integer('is_active')->default(0);

        $table->tinyInteger('verified')->default(0);
        $table->string('email_token')->nullable();

        $table->text('address');
        $table->string('district');

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And then for the lesson schedules

```
Schema::create('lessons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('status'); //0 - not started, 1 - completed, 2 - no show

        $table->dateTime('start_at');
        $table->dateTime('end_at');

        $table->dateTime('started_at');
        $table->dateTime('ended_at');

        $table->string('unique_id')->unique();

 $table->integer('teacher_id')->unsigned();
          $table->foreign('teacher_id')
              ->references('id')->on('users')
              ->onUpdate('cascade')
              ->onDelete('cascade');

          $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned();
          $table->foreign('student_id')
              ->references('id')->on('users')
              ->onUpdate('cascade')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('completed');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

if i want to display my data on the view for this. How do i add the relations to the various models and how do i display them to view.

I believe this is a belongsToMany relations

Pleas help!

how do i do this?

Not sure if i clear enough

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a pivot may restrict you somewhat, and make things more complicated.

Instead, why not create a model such as `Schedule`?

```
Student has many Schedule
Schedule belongs to a Student
Schedule belongs to a Teacher
Schedule belongs to a Lesson
Student has many Lesson through Schedule
```

This also allows you to expand on this further since you're dealing with a model specifically for the purpose.

Comment: So it's better to have a model for student and teacher not role??

Comment: I'm guessing that you have one user that can be multiple types? It entirely depends. I'd imagine that students and teachers have very different functionality, so it may be easier to just give them different users.